# Simpy - How to use Filter Store asynchronously

Tags: python, simpy

I am using Simpy to model machine repair work.  Machines can come in to the factory to be repaired, assigned a technician, and then work on the repair until it is done.

I am using Filter Store to keep track of technicians.

```
NUM_TECHNICIANS = 3               # number of technicians
REPAIR_TIME = 5              # time to repair machine in hours

def task_network(technicians):

    # Request a technician    
    t = yield technicians.get()
    print("Assigned to Technician %d at time %d" % (t.id, env.now))
    yield env.process(t.repair_machine(machine1))

    t = yield technicians.get(lambda t: t.fatigue < 30)
    print("Assigned to Technician %d at time %d" % (t.id, env.now))
    yield env.process(t.repair_machine(machine2))

class Machine(object):
    def __init__(self, env, id, type, isBroken):
        self.env = env
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
        self.isBroken = isBroken

class Technician(object):
    def __init__(self, env, id, skill_level, fatigue, shifts_remaining):
        self.env = env
        self.id = id
        self.skill_level = skill_level
        self.fatigue = fatigue
        self.shifts_remaining = shifts_remaining
        self.isAvailable = True

    def repair_machine(self, machine):
        if machine.type == "MN152":
            self.fatigue += 10
            self.shifts_remaining -= 0.25
            self.isAvailable = False
            print("Repairing...")
            yield env.timeout(REPAIR_TIME)
            print("Technician %d is done repairing at time %d" % (self.id, env.now))

env = simpy.Environment()

# Filter Store allows us to have processes ask for objects as resources (the technicians)
# and get them based off of some criteria (e.g. this radio is complex so requires a more experienced technician)
# If no criteria is specified, Filter Store is FIFO
technicians = simpy.FilterStore(env, capacity = NUM_TECHNICIANS)

t0 = Technician(env, id=0, skill_level=74, fatigue=15, shifts_remaining=2)
t1 = Technician(env, id=1, skill_level=45, fatigue=50, shifts_remaining=1)
t2 = Technician(env, id=2, skill_level=56, fatigue=0, shifts_remaining=3)

technicians.put(jt0)
technicians.put(jt1)
technicians.put(jt2)

machine1 = Machine(env, id=0, type="MN150", isBroken=True)
machine2 = Machine(env, id=1, type="MN152", isBroken=True)

env.process(task_network(technicians))
env.run()
```

The above code runs as it should and prints

```
Assigned to Technician 0 at time 0
Repairing...
Technician 0 is done repairing at time 5
Assigned to Technician 2 at time 5
Repairing...
Technician 2 is done repairing at time 10
```

However, how do I make it such that machines can come in, be assigned, and repaired and returned asynchronously?  Currently (because of my `yield` statements), the simulation suspends until the `yield` process returns which is why it waits until one machine is done repairing before starting another machine repair job.  There are three technicians in the store so it should allow all three to repair and return machines asynchronously.  How do I achieve this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spawn multiple processes and then use [Environment.all_of](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/simpy.core.html#simpy.core.Environment.all_of) to wait for them:

```
procs = [env.process(my_task() for _ in range(3))

# do other stuff ...

results = yield env.all_of(procs)
```

Comment: This helped me.  Thank you!